# torch.jit.script(module) vs @torch.jit.script decorator

Tags: pytorch, torchscript

Why is adding the decorator "@torch.jit.script" results in an error, while I can call torch.jit.script on that module, e.g. this fails:

```py
import torch
    
@torch.jit.script
class MyCell(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCell, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(4, 4)

    def forward(self, x, h):
        new_h = torch.tanh(self.linear(x) + h)
        return new_h, new_h
    
my_cell = MyCell()
x, h = torch.rand(3, 4), torch.rand(3, 4)
traced_cell = torch.jit.script(my_cell, (x, h))
print(traced_cell)
traced_cell(x, h)
```

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py", line 1262, in script
    raise RuntimeError("Type '{}' cannot be compiled since it inherits"
RuntimeError: Type '<class '__main__.MyCell'>' cannot be compiled since it inherits from nn.Module, pass an instance instead
```

While the following code works well:

```py
class MyCell(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCell, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(4, 4)
    
    def forward(self, x, h):
        new_h = torch.tanh(self.linear(x) + h)
        return new_h, new_h
    
my_cell = MyCell()
x, h = torch.rand(3, 4), torch.rand(3, 4)
traced_cell = torch.jit.script(my_cell, (x, h))
print(traced_cell)
traced_cell(x, h)
```

This question is also featured on [PyTorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-jit-script-module-vs-torch-jit-script-decorator/92735).

Comment: If you get more in-depth explanation from PyTorch forums please post it here as self-answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for your error is [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/jit_language_reference.html#id2), this bulletpoint precisely:

> No support for inheritance or any other polymorphism strategy, except
> for inheriting from object to specify a new-style class.

Also, as stated at the top:

> TorchScript class support is experimental. Currently it is best suited
> for simple record-like types (think a NamedTuple with methods
> attached).

Currently, it's purpose is for simple **Python** classes (see other points in the link I've provided) and functions, see link I've provided for more information.

You can also check [`torch.jit.script` source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/jit/_script.py#L735) to get a better grasp of how it works.

From what it seems, when you pass an instance, all `attributes` which should be preserved are recursively parsed ([source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/jit/_script.py#L887)). You can follow this function along (quite commented, but too long for an answer, see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/jit/_recursive.py#L294)), though exact reason why this is the case (and why it was designed this way) is beyond my knowledge (so hopefully someone with expertise in `torch.jit`'s inner workings will speak more about it).